# SciTE can not find user defined function. The editor executes "/bin/sh" for some reason

Tags: lua, text-editor, scite

So, this is my first attempt to make my source code editing more comfortable. I follow the `SciTE` scripting guide.

```
ext.lua.startup.script=$(SciteDefaultHome)/startup.lua

command.name.1.*= Programmer's Manual (selected text)
command.subsystem.1.*= 3
command.1.*=man_select
command.shortcut.1.*=F1
```

Above is the user properties file. It binds `F1` key to user defined `Lua` function.

The problem is, that insteed of starting the function, `man_select` in my case, the `SciTE` editor output gives me

```
>man_select
/bin/sh: man_select: not found
>Exit code: 127
```

So, the editor runs a shell with my function name as a argument. I can't find no `SciTE` logs, or console, to see what the cause is.

I define `man_select` as a simple Lua function, without arguments:

```
function man_select()
   local sel = editor:GetSelText()
   ...
end
```

What should I do to make my own `Lua` functions visible to `SciTE` editor? Is there a way to ask `SciTE` for more information on its scripting system flow?

Comment: Remove space between `=` and `3`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff can you point me to, where can I read about `command.subsystem.1.*`, i.e subsystems in use by scite?

Comment: Subsystems in use by SciTE are documented here: https://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html . By the way: I don't know how to ask SciTE for more information on its scripting system flow. Maybe there is no way to ask SciTE about it?

Comment: @Claudio More like mentioned, "documented" is too much of a word for that.